# Intermediate Chess Books

Tags: books

Does anyone have any suggestions for intermediate chess books? Tactics or endgames would be the topic that I'd mainly like to focus on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot go wrong with the Yusupov and Aagaard series of books. Both are tremendous. Yusupov's books cover everything, and not in any order, so one day, you will get some tactics, endgames, and maybe even some opening stuff. They are very varied.

Yusupov was a top-10 player, multiple-time candidate, and considered one of the greatest trainers living today.

You might also like Quality Chess' "The Woodpecker Method", which is an immersion course in tactics.

You can find them [here](https://www.qualitychess.co.uk/sections/13/special_offers/).

New in Chess also has a lot of books aimed at the intermediate market:

1. Improve Your Chess Pattern Recognition
2. Train Your Chess Pattern Recognition
3. Strategic Chess Excercises
4. Complete Manual of Positional Chess volumes 1 and 2.

Some of these are not tactics, but they are still problems that are designed to have you analyze.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll make sure to check those out!

Comment: I have been collecting chess books for 40 years, and books today are better than ever for learning the game. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so early, I'm going to make sure to get these ordered so I can start improving =)

Comment: I wish you the best in your studies.

Comment: Thanks! My Lichess username is: Walkerboy ,if you're ever interested in playing a few games!

Comment: could you be more specific with what you mean by intermediate - I've seen 2300s call themselves "average joe" and met 1300s who think they are GMs :D

Comment: @Hamish 1600-2000 is what I would call "intermediate". Of course, they have books that cater to virtually everyone over 1200, and it is not a hard-and-fast rule, but they have a lot aimed at that market (and it is quality material).